# Iterate cell value exceljs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, exceljs

I want to know how can I iterate a json in a foreach and set the value to the cells F13 over the loop ends it can stop at F14 or F26 I have check the documentation but I don't understand very well about how can I make it
I brought the data from the data base I've a field with the name steps in this field I store JSON.

My json is like this

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "paso": "Paso 1",
    "accion": "1",
    "punto_critico": "1",
    "razon": "1",
    "fichero": ""
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "paso": "Paso 2",
    "accion": "accion 2",
    "punto_critico": "punto critico 2",
    "razon": "razon 2",
    "fichero": ""
  }
]
```

I try like the response that gave me progm but throwme a error of `this.data.forEach is not a function` As data I change the `this.data` to a variable name that I create giving it the json as value

Answer (score 0):

I added a simple example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as Excel from 'exceljs/dist/exceljs.min.js';

export interface PersonModel {
  firstName: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
  data = [
    {
      "firstName": "Brian"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Tom"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Alisa"
    }
  ]

  constructor() {
    const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('test-worksheet');

    worksheet.columns = [
      { key: 'firstName' }
    ];

    this.data.forEach((value: PersonModel) => {
      worksheet.addRow(value);
    });
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to the example. just one more question. How can I start from a specific cell like for example F25